# .NET Core Web API - Cannot INSERT record calling an Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

When I send a POST to WebAPI using Postman the record is created successfully, but when I run it from code I am receiving an "**ORA-03115: unsupported network datatype or representation**".

Here's my Oracle 11g Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_REGION(ROMANO IN REGION.ROMANO%TYPE,NOMBRE IN REGION.NOMBRE%TYPE, RESULTADO_OK OUT BOOLEAN )
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO REGION (ID,ROMANO,NOMBRE)
VALUES(SEQ_REGION.NEXTVAL,ROMANO,NOMBRE);
COMMIT;
RESULTADO_OK :=TRUE ;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN RESULTADO_OK:=FALSE ;
END ADD_REGION;
```

My code in .NET Core WebAPI:

```
OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("ADD_REGION", conn);
command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

OracleParameter InNombre = command.Parameters.Add("NOMBRE", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
InNombre.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
InNombre.Value = "Test Name";

OracleParameter InRomano = command.Parameters.Add("ROMANO", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
InRomano.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
InRomano.Value = "Test Romano";

OracleParameter OUTparameter = command.Parameters.Add("RESULTADO_OK", OracleDbType.Boolean);
OUTparameter.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

command.ExecuteNonQuery();

return (bool)(OracleBoolean)OUTparameter.Value;
```

The line that is causing the Exception is:

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I've been stuck with this problem for a while, so I'd appreciate some guidance.

Regards,

Pablo.

PS: I'm using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core 2.19.50.

Comment: Can you try to run with `command..executeQuery();`  and share the result.

Comment: OracleCommand does not have a definition for ExecuteQuery(). I tried with ExecuteReader() and I've got the same error explained above.

Comment: I notice you are passing the parameters in a different named sequence - can't see that being the cause of the error but it won't help the result.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide connectionstring your string information (except your password ,of course)

Comment: Finally I could solve it. The problem was the BOOLEAN parameter, I used INTEGER data type and it worked. Then, I parse it in the application to bool.